# How can I search bookmarks and history stored on mobile safari within iOS?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

Within desktop Safari, one can view and edit bookmarks within a a hiearchical list.

For Mobile-Safari running on an iPad: How do you view all bookmarks? How do you search within Bookmarks?

Answer (score 1):

There is no interface for searching within Mobile Safari.

There is no secondary viewing options other than tapping and pawing through the history UI that mobile safari draws when you tap the book icon to the right of the navigation arrows at the top of the screen.

In the absence of a native solution, you can get at the history and bookmarks once you connect an iOS device to a computer.

On Mac OS, you can use a tool like [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) to archive all data from an iOS device, and this archive includes mobile Safari's web history and bookmarks so you can make fast work of searching the 8 days of device history once you have the data on your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 6 or so, if you type in the safari searchbar it also looks up your bookmarks and sites in the history. I think I can remember that there is/was a switch in the settings.

Also you have now the possibility to search content in webpage, just enter your search terms into the address bar, and results will return in order of:

- Google Search
- Bookmarks and History
- On This Page